# I install a Hunter ceiling fan/light per instructions with dual switches. The fan works but the light does not

Tags: ceiling-fan

I install a Hunter ceiling fan/light with dual switches. The fan work but the light does not. Pull chain switch has electrical current going into it but no current going out to the lights when chain is pulled.

Comment: Could you post the installation instructions or do you have a model number?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.